# call python3 class with methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, instantiation

I have a file named: scrape.py This file contains the following class:

Im trying to call my class `BrickSetSpider`, with its methods, and ultimately return the value of `parse_page_urls` when running this program like `python scrape.py`.

However, when i run `python scrape.py`, I get:

> NameError: name 'response' is not defined

on this line:

```
page = spider.parse_se_page_url(response)
```

Can someone help me run my two methods (outputting the result of `g_result_list` ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you specify the problem? After your update? It will also help if you post code of both classes

Comment: There is only `1 class` with 2 methods: `parse_page_url`, and `parse_page_urls`

Comment: I updated my problem when i run the current code above @GiladGreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thins:

- The reason you get the error of `NameError: name 'response' is not defined` is that no where in the scope of main you have defined any variable called `response`
  You can't use it without defining such a parameter.
- In addition in the `parse_se_page_urls` you have an extra line of

  ```
  def parse_se_page_urls(self, g_result_page):
  ```

  without any implementation of the function. should also be problematic.
- Unless missing something that isn't in the code posted, in your second function you are using the `g_result_page` variable - but just as with response it is not defined.
  You have a parameter with the same name in the function above but it is a local variable of that function and thus unknown by the second one. To initialize them as members of the instance add a constructor as follows:

  ```
  def __init__(self):
      self.g_result_list = []
      self.g_result_page = []
  ```

  and then for using write `self.g_result_page`
- In your first function you have the two following lines:

  ```
  set(g_result_page)
  list(g_result_page)
  ```

  These lines have no effect - they create a `set` and a `list` out of `g_result_page` but these data structures are not assigned to anything and thus are cleared at the end of the function

Comment: This is all in the same `class`, just with 2 `methods` method 2 calling method 1

Comment: @Giliad - doesnt it come from the class `BrickSetSpider()` upon inital class definition?

Answer (score 0):

There are two minor errors in your code.

First, when you get an instance of the class, you don't need to pass in anything, so your code becomes

```
spider = BrickSetSpider()
```

Secondly, you use the variable `page` to store the output of `spider.parse_page_url(response)` by doing `page = spider.parse_page_url(response)`, but you then call `urls = page.parse_page_urls(result_page)`. I believe what you meant to do was call `urls = spider.parse_page_urls(page)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying I should keep `page` var, but remove `url` var, and instead just use its contents of `page.parse_page_urls(page` ?

Comment: Unfortunately on `page` var line, i get this error when i run `python scrape.py` : `NameError: name 'response' is not defined`

Comment: Well yes, if you are going to scrape a page, you first need a page to scrape, don't you? You need to figure out what type of data your `parse_page_url()` function needs, and how to get that. We would need to see the code for that function to help you with that.

Comment: I updated my code for the `methods` and the problem im experiencing

Comment: The simple answer is that you never said what `response` was. You cant expect it to magically ask you for a url or something.

Comment: `response` contains a url like `website.com/search/page1`. Upon running `parse_se_page_url()`, the output is more values like `website.com/search/result1, website.com/search/result2` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134313/discussion-between-blucode-and-jshee).